# codeigniter join multiple rows where

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, left-join

I'm trying to code a search function for a site written on CodeIgniter but have trouble with the join statement in the model.

A controller passes an array of search criteria to the model function: get_sales($search_criteria);

```
function get_sales($search_criterie){

    $this->db->join('sales_prices', 'sales_prices.sale_id = sales.sale_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('sales_sizes', 'sales_sizes.sale_id = sales.sale_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('sales', $search_criterie);
    $sale_data = $query->result_array();

}
```

I'm running into two problems:

1) I need a WHERE clause in the sales_sizes join. Right now it joins sales_sizes.sale_id ON sales.sale_id but I want to be able to filter by size via the $search_criteria array. How can I do this?

2) Every sales usually has multiple sizes and I want the output of the query formatted like:

```
Array
(
    [sale_id] => 1
    [sale_category] => shoes
    [sale_price] => 29.99
    [sale_sizes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 10.5
            [2] => 11

        )

)
```

I've tried some foreach loops to format the output but can't get it to work. Hope somebody can help.

Update:

How do I process the following query result into a format like the one above?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sale_id] => 1
            [sale_category] => shoes
            [sale_price] => 29.99
            [sale_size] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sale_id] => 1
            [sale_category] => shoes
            [sale_price] => 29.99
            [sale_size] => 10.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sale_id] => 1
            [sale_category] => shoes
            [sale_price] => 29.99
            [sale_size] => 11    
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried grouping by sales_sizes?

Comment: I think in order to return a number of sizes for each sale you would actually have to group by sale_id, sale_category and sale_price.  This however would just return a number of records all with different sizes but the same other columns.  In order to get the format of the array you want you would have to do some post processing and throw them into an array based on the returned results.

Comment: agree that I need to process the output query, but I don't know how to. I've updated the question with the output I need processed..

Answer (score 1):

I am personally not a big fan of using the active record as given. I find that it often restricts the programmer from writing more complex queries. If you find that this is true as well you could rewrite your query as followed:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `sales_prices`, `sales_sizes` WHERE `sales_prices`.`sale_id` =   `sales`.`sale_id` AND `sales_sizes`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`sale_id` AND `sales`  = ?', array($search_criterie));
$sale_data = $query->results();
```

This will generate the same result and will also parameterize your query. Note that the question mark corresponds in order to values in your array that will make up the second parameter of you `$this->db->query()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this type of query**

```
$this->db->select('places.*, category.*')
            ->from('places')
            ->join('category', 'places.category_id = category.category_id', 'left')
            ->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id', 'left')
            ->where('places.category_id', $category_id)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

Comment: regarding my 2nd problem, the output is still not formatted the right way

if a sale has multiple sizes, a new array with duplicate content for same sale_id is returned for every size... 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sale_id] => 1
            [sale_category] => shoes
            [sale_price] => 29.99
            [sale_size] => 10

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [sale_id] => 1
            [sale_category] => shoes
            [sale_price] => 29.99
            [sale_size] => 11

        )

)

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will work for you, it won't generate exact output, but very close to one.

```
$this->db->select('sales.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sales_prices.sale_id) as sales_price GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sales_sizes.sale_id) as sales_size')
```

This will generate a comma separated value for you.